# Using Excel VBA to save a file where the filename contains the next Wednesday or Saturday (whichever is sooner), on or after a date given in the file

Tags: vba, excel

I've searched all over for an answer to this but not quite found what I'm looking for specifically.

Essentially I have a macro which edits and saves a template file under a new name with a prefix and (currently), the date of the closest Saturday based on today's date. This was fine for past purposes however now I need to do the same but for either Saturday OR Wednesday (whichever comes first), based on a selected date within the file. For example, if in the file the date given was Thu 3rd August, the file would save as "prefix - August 5", whereas if it was Tue 1st August, the file would save as "prefix - August 2". It also needs to save as the same day, should I save it on a Wednesday or a Saturday.

Not sure if this is even possible. The current line of code (to save as following Saturday) is as follows:

`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Andrew\Downloads\Test\" & "Predictions - " & Format(Date + 7 - Weekday(Date, vbSunday), "mmmm dd") & ".xlsm"`

The date in the file is in A17.

First time I've asked a question anywhere on here - other people's answers have served me so well since I started messing with VBA so I'm hoping there is someone out there who can make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If Weekday(Date, vbSunday) < Weekday(Date, vbThursday) Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Andrew\Downloads\Test\" & "Predictions - " & Format(Date + 7 - Weekday(Date, vbThursday), "mmmm dd") & ".xlsm"
Else
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Andrew\Downloads\Test\" & "Predictions - " & Format(Date + 7 - Weekday(Date, vbSunday), "mmmm dd") & ".xlsm"
End If
```

This modifies your existing code to work out the next Wednesday and the next Saturday then it works out which comes first and applies that code.

Comment: True afk at the moment will fix tomorrow.

Comment: Fixed to compare the dates, rather than the date-strings.

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to look at the next Wednesday or Saturday after or on a specific date within the spreadsheet. Would I be able to use this code for that?

Comment: I really should play around with the code first before commenting! Replaced all six 'Date's with Range("A17") and it seems to be working perfectly. Ta very much :)

Comment: Yes. Replace each Date with Range("A1").Value

Comment: Sorry that I didn't have time to elaborate on the code.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

### Usage

> getWorkBookName(#7/27/2017#,"C:\Users\Andrew\Downloads\Test\")

```
Function getWorkBookName(DateOf As Date, RootDirectory)
    If Weekday(DateOf, vbSunday) <= 4 Then
        getWorkBookName = RootDirectory & "Predictions - " & Format(DateOf + vbWednesday - Weekday(DateOf, vbSunday), "mmmm dd") & ".xlsm"
    Else
        getWorkBookName = RootDirectory & "Predictions - " & Format(DateOf + vbSaturday - Weekday(DateOf, vbSunday), "mmmm dd") & ".xlsm"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Ignore my past comment - I am an idiot! I have got it working but for some reason it's not picking up the date in the range - I'll have to play around a bit. Thanks though, v. helpful!